# How to hide/show linestring in openlayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have two LineStrings drawing at the same time

```
  var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
  var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ source: vectorSource });
  var drawLine = new ol.interaction.Draw({
      source: vectorSource,
      type: 'LineString'
  });


  var vectorSourceHide = new ol.source.Vector();
  var vectorLayerHide = new ol.layer.Vector({ source: vectorSourceHide });
  var drawLineHide = new ol.interaction.Draw({
      source: vectorSourceHide,
      type: 'LineString'
  });

  map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
  map.addLayer(vectorLayerHide);
```

and then in some statement I need to finish drawing the first line and **hide second line**, and then in another statement I need to **show again the second line**
so it should look like this -

```
if(true){
drawLine.finishDrawing();
//how to hide drawLineHide ???????   }

if(false){
//how to show drawLineHide ??????? }
```

Please write how to hide/show this line if you know.

Comment: Have you tried `map.removeLayer(vectorLayer)`? OpenLayers 2 or 3? Please don't tag both

Comment: @chrki  yes, I've done it. Btun now I have another question - how to continue drawing drawline after double click? so we have line drawend and then if we click on the map again we shouldn't add another line, we should continue drawing this line